# ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['pytz'] after install

Tags: python

I am receiving this error when I run pandas:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
"Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['pytz']
```

All was fine until after I installed `numpy‑1.14.1+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl`. 
I uninstalled `pandas` and `numpy` and tried reinstalling. That didn't work.

My environment variables is set to the `"C:\Python27"`. `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` does have `pytz`.

I've also tried `easy_install pytz` and gave me `already satisfied`. 
Is there a way I can revert back to where I was before I installed numpy+mkl or fix this error?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try uninstalling pytz and reinstalling it?

Comment: if you `import sys` and `print(sys.path)`, is `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` in that list?

Comment: @LeviLesches yes I did

Comment: @JacobIRR yes it is

Comment: Hm, try uninstalling Panda and numpy like you said, also uninstall pytz, then install Panda and numpy and then pytz (in that order). Other than that, there's not much I can do as it probably involves looking at specific things in your computer